# Help me SELECT thumbnail from SQL and use

Tags: sql, select

```
//MySQL Username
$user = "myuser";
//MySQL Password
$pass = "mypass";
//MySQL Database Name
$database = "mydb";
//Number of posts you want to have appear
$numOfPosts = 7;

//Setup connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $database);
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$limit = $numOfPosts;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status IN ( 'draft', 'publish', 'future', 'pending', 'private','attachment' ) ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $limit";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li><a href="'.$row->guid.'" title="'.$row->post_title.'"target="_blank">'.$row->post_title.'</a></li>';
  echo '</ul>';

}
```

Comment: I changed the database connection information to something generic. Never post those credentials online and you should log in to your server and change that information ___immediately___.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using Wordpress database functions?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to be messing with the database connection. WordPress provide a database object called `$wpdb`.

It is not really clear what you are doing. Your title reads "help me select thumb", but your code is actually pulling a lot of different post statuses, not thumbnails. In fact, your code does not have anything to do with thumbnails at all, that I can tell, except that some attachments are thumbnails.

This will pull and display thumbnails only.

```
$numOfPosts = 10;
$thumbs = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' LIMIT {$numOfPosts}");
foreach ($thumbs as $thumb) {
  echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumb); 
}
```

You can use your own SQL if need be...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status IN ( 'draft', 'publish', 'future', 'pending', 'private','attachment' ) ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $limit";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

I am fairly sure you could do this with `WP_Query` though. Something like:

```
$numOfPosts = 10;
$thumbs = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'posts_per_page' => $numOfPosts,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => array( 'draft', 'publish', 'future', 'pending', 'private','attachment' ),
  )
);
if ($thumbs->have_posts()) {
  while ($thumbs->have_posts()) {
    $thumbs->the_post();
    echo '<ul>';
      echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'"target="_blank">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

Again, I am not really sure what you are trying to do.